# How do I find another root of polynomial in this case?

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

Observe $f=x^3-5$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$. So we can write $f=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^2+3x+9$. How do we find another root?

This problem is related to finding a splitting field extension. I suppose that I should get that 2nd root is $\alpha$ times something and in that way I would have that $\mathbb{Z}_{11}(\alpha)$ is desired splitting field, but I don't know how to find another root. How can it be done?

What is the general approach to the problems like this?

Comment: By Vieta's formulas, the second root is $-3-\alpha$ or $\frac9\alpha$. Whichever one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

as you already have the root $3,$  let $\omega$  be a root of
$$t^2 + t + 1$$
and thus a new cube root of $1.$  The cube roots of $5$  are now $3, 3 \omega, 3 \omega^2.$

Note that $t= \omega^2$  is also a root of $t^2 + t + 1,$   since $\omega^4 = \omega$

Comment: How does that relate to the root $\alpha$ of $x^2+3x+9$?

Comment: @lhf  the roots of $t^2 + 3t + 9$ are $3 \omega, 3 \omega^2 $

Comment: How do you know that you should work with $t^2+t+1$? Can you add some more details? What's about Don Thousand's comment?